# Убрать padding для внутреннего элемента

Tags: css

Если у body стоит `padding: 0px 10px;`, как можно убрать этот стиль у одного из внутренних элементов, а то отступы остаются, а их не должно быть - в футере, как минимум?

Как пример:

styles:

```
body {padding: 0px 10px;}
```

code:

```
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

В footer в данном случае не должно быть padding.

Comment: пример кода приведите пожалуйста...

Comment: #content {padding: 0}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае поможет свойство box-sizing

```
#footer{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Или же просто убрать паддинг

```
#footer{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Хотя я мог не правильно вас понять. Вы задаете паддинг для родителя. Что бы футер грубо говоря игнорировал этот отступ из вне, можно дать футеру отрицательный margin который будет равен отступу * -1

```
#footer{
    margin: 0 -10px;
}
```

Comment: Только последний вариант сработал, но сработал.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Вот это создаёт отступ, а не `padding` в основном документе, поэтому зануляем.